# Mocking a method in a class dynamically

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am pretty new to Mockito and Spring.
I am trying to mock many methods of many classes. I want to create a functionality where bean name and method name can given as input as string, and it will throw same exception.

Example 
 I have a class A and Class B

```
@Named
public Class A {
   public void methodInA() {
   System.out.println("In A"); 
  }
}

@Named
public Class B {
   public void methodInB() {
   System.out.println("In B"); 
  }
}
```

Below is what I am trying to do in test.

TestConfig:

```
@SpyBean
A a;
```

Test::

```
String className = "A";
String methodName = "methodInA";


Object bean = applicationContext.getBean("a");
Class clazzToSpy = bean.getClass();

Class[] paramTypes = clazzToSpy.getMethod(methodName);

Answer answer = new Answer() {
@Override
public Object answer(final InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
   if(invocationOnMock.getMethod().getName().equals(methodName)) {
       throw new UnknownError("Manual Exception Created");
   }
   return invocationOnMock.callRealMethod();

  }
};

//Here I want to use the answer on the mock Something like below.

Method mockedMethod = clazzToSpy.getMethod(methodName, paramTypes);

Mockito.doAnswer(answer).when(mockedMethod)
```

I understand there is a gap in my understanding.
How do I achieve something like above?

Has someone tried doing similar thing?

Related threads which I have tried:

1. [Mocking Reflection based calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011129/mocking-reflection-based-calls/9011651)
2. [Mocking getClass method with PowerMockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251424/mocking-getclass-method-with-powermockito?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. [mockito : mock method call with parameters by reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109768/mockito-mock-method-call-with-parameters-by-reflection)
4. [Mockito: is it possible to combine mock with a method name to create a methodCall inside a when() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124482/mockito-is-it-possible-to-combine-mock-with-a-method-name-to-create-a-methodcal)
5. [Using Mockito to mock methods by reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970810/using-mockito-to-mock-methods-by-reflection)

Comment: How exactly does it not work? A compile error since [`Class.getMethod(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class...)) returns `Method`, of course, rather than `Class[]`? (And, BTW, `Error` ← `VirtualMachineError` („Thrown to indicate that the Java Virtual Machine is broken or has run out of resources necessary for it to continue operating.“) ← `UnknownError` reads: „Thrown when an unknown but serious exception has occurred in the Java Virtual Machine.“ This is surely not what you want to throw yourself.)

Comment: Hi GeroldBroser, this gives me unfinished stubbing exception.

Answer (score 0):

This seems not going to work since when you:

```java
@Spy
Method methodSpy;
```

Mockito throws:

> ```java
> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Unable to initialize @Spy annotated field 'methodSpy'.
> Please ensure that the type 'Method' has a no-arg constructor.
> ```

and if you:

```java
@Mock
Method methodMock;
```

it throws:

> ```java
> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
> Cannot mock/spy class java.lang.reflect.Method
> Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
>     - final class
> ```

at:

```java
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );
```